# How can I change bar color between two ticks - Plotly.js

Tags: javascript, plotly.js

I would like to change the bars color between ticks. For example: bars between 1st and 2nd January on 'green', between 2nd and 3rd January on 'red' and loop that bars between 3rd and 4th January will be again 'green'.
I think I have to use marker option but don't know how.

Code:

```
        var col = ['green', 'red', 'green']
        
        var cisnienie_plot = {
            x: zakres,
            y: cisnienie,
            type: 'bar',
            marker: {color: col},
        };
        var data = [cisnienie_plot];
        var layout = {
            xaxis: {
                range: [wybrana_data_od, wybrana_data_do],
                tick0: wybrana_data_od,
                dtick: 86400000,
        },
        yaxis: {range: [min_of_cisnienie-2, max_of_cisnienie+2]}
        };
        Plotly.newPlot('chart', data, layout);
```

Output of code:
[barchart.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7KJj.png)

Answer (score 0):

For looping or repeating your mark colors,

Maybe Plotly.js doesn't support that, but you can trickly create your **marker color array** like this by repeating your base color **col** array until it reachs **zakres.length**.

```
marker: {color: Array(zakres.length).fill(col).flat().splice(0, zakres.length)}
```

For eg:

```
Array(5).fill(['green', 'red']).flat().splice(0, 5)
```

Result:

```
(5) ["green", "red", "green", "red", "green"]
```

Live demo with Plotly.js for you here:
https://codepen.io/daubac402/pen/vYyMpGW